# The leading zeroes challenge

Tags: code-golf, string

## The challenge

Given two integers as input (`x` and `y`), output `x` as a string with as many leading zeroes necessary for it to be `y` characters long without the sign.

### Rules

- If `x` has more than `y` digits, output `x` as string without modification.
- Output as integer is not accepted, even if there are no leading zeroes.
- When `x` is negative, keep the `-` as is and operate on the absolute value.
- Negative `y` should be treated as 0, meaning you output `x` as is (but as string)

#### Examples:

```
IN: (1,1)   OUT: "1"
IN: (1,2)   OUT: "01"
IN: (10,1)  OUT: "10"
IN: (-7,3)  OUT: "-007"
IN: (-1,1)  OUT: "-1"
IN: (10,-1) OUT: "10"
IN: (0,0)   OUT: "0"
IN: (0,1)   OUT: "0"
IN: (0,4)   OUT: "0000"
```

Shortest code in bytes wins, standard loopholes apply.

Comment: sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14264/69737

Comment: Can I take x as string?

Comment: what does `(-1,1)` give?

Comment: @Adám added it to the examples.

Comment: wow this appeared on the HNQ, i'm happy my first challenge is so well received :D

Comment: Test case suggestion: `-5, -4`

Comment: codegolf questions with snazzy titles almost aways do hit the HNQ. But it is a very good feeling, congrats.

Comment: Is a leading `+` sign acceptable for positive numbers?

Comment: Most answers are based on `printf` if you change it they would all get better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>13</s> 8 bytes

Takes first input (`x`) as a string.

```
®©ùTV}'-
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rqn5VFZ9Jy0=&input=Ii04IiwtOA==)

Saved a massive 5 bytes thanks to ETHproductions.

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of string `U=x` and integer `V=y`.

`®   }'-` splits `U` to an array on the minus symbol, maps over it and rejoins it to a string with a minus symbol.

`©` is logical AND (`&&`) so if the current element is truthy (a non-empty string) then pad left (`ù`) with 0 (`T`) to length `V`.

Comment: Nice one! You can save quite a bit by simply mapping around `-`: https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rqn5VFZ9Jy0=&input=Ii04Iiw4

Comment: @ETHproductions: Great call. Thanks. Been so long since I've done so, I'd completely forgotten you can split, map and rejoin a string all in one method!

Comment: Yes, I suppose that functionality should be moved to `q`, which would then be `q-_©ùTV` to save 1 byte :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions, if I'm understanding that right, you're suggesting that if a function is passed as a second argument of `S.q()` (giving us `S.q(s,f)`) then `S` would be split on `s`, run through `f` and rejoined with `s`? I like it! :)

Comment: Yeah, did I talk to Oliver and not you about doing that (if passed a function, do the normal functionality, run through the function, and undo the first change; `N.s`, `S/A.y`, `N.ì` do this already) with a bunch of methods? I had a conversation with someone, I just can't remember who now :s

Answer (score 8):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
%"%0*d",+E>0
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22%250%2ad%22%2C%2BE%3E0&input=-7%0A3&debug=0)**

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:x.zfill(y+(x<'.'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9KqQq8qLTMnR6NSW6PCRl1PXVPzf0lqcUmxgq1CNJcCEGioG6rrKBhq6iDxjBA8AxRJXXMg1xjOBUkaoKrVNdTkiuVKyy8C2q5QqZCZpwC2zgqspqAoM69EIU0DJKX5HwA)

Just `str.zfill` comes so close.

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 29 bytes

Take input as `f(x,y)`. Using Python's `%` operator.

```python
lambda x,y:'%0*d'%(y+(x<0),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9JKXdVAK0VdVaNSW6PCxkBTp0Lzf0lqcUlyYnGqgq1CtIahjqGmDpA0ApEGYI6uuY4xkDLQMYCI6RpqxnKl5RcpZOpkKWTmKcD0WykUFGXmlWikaQAlNDX/AwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

Input given as `amount_of_digits, number`

```
ÎIÄg-×ì'-†
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cJ/n4ZZ03cPTD69R133UsOD/f2MuXXMA)

**Explanation**

```
Î            # push 0 and first input
 IÄ          # push the absolute value of the second input
   g         # length
    -        # subtract, (input1-len(abs(input2))
     ×       # repeat the zero that many times
      ì      # prepend to the second input
       '-†   # move any "-" to the front
```

Comment: Seems like this is the winning answer so far, if not bettered tomorrow i'll accept it.

Comment: you've been outgolfed :(

Comment: @BrianH. Indeed I have :)

Answer (score 5):

## C#, 56 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##lY9RS8MwFIXf8ysufVnClpHqw6BdKyL4NHGg4oP4cJtlJbCmJckEkf32mraoVRjUQyD3HvLdcyMdl7VV7dFpU8LDu/OqSgkxWCnXoFRwUxtXH9R108Tkg0CQPKBzsLV1abHqncHv5Dx6LeGt1ju4Q22o8zYMfnkFtKVj3@9@iE63RyPX2vjFqBrAPId9sCBrMcuLLKe4FlcRj5IoYnPadxwTZPPQL7e426i9p0VwRVIsZmLG2nSUQ75@s3y22quNNop242nMwoE5RHD/9JhAHLH014LnsYse6ykxGRN/4sREkK8YvRyBXIjVRDREihEp/rEqP7/riRAy3CfSfgI)

```
a=>b=>(a<0?"-":"")+((a<0?-a:a)+"").PadLeft(b<0?0:b,'0')
```

Answer (score 5):

## **[Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>28</s> 37 bytes**

```py
lambda x,y:f'{x:0{(y,0)[y<0]+(x<0)}}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvBCoMwEETv/Yq9maUrbPRQCPol6iGthqa0UTSHBPHb01To5Q0zw1uif86uTqbt01t/7qOGQFGZYg@KdxGJsYsND1cRGsbjKJKfNv/Q2wQtdEKSRMqsfuSzlDeqc3A2z62UOFzMvIKlF1gHf1/BslrnhRH5QExf) (Test case from Colera Su's answer)

Taking advantage of the new way to format strings in python 3.6

+9 bytes to handle `y<0`

Comment: Looks like this fails when `y` is negative: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9IqTb26wsqgulJbo8LGQLO2Vv1/QVFmXolGmoahgY6uoabmfwA

Comment: Indeed. So i'm up with 37 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 47 bytes

```java
x->y->"".format("%0"+((y<1?1:y)-(x>>31))+"d",x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc49a8MwEIDh3b/iEBSkphJ2UygkqboVOnTKWDqodhzkyJKwzsGi5Le7Jh8moz3pOD28XKWOiju/s1Vx6HXtXYNQDTvRojaibG2O2lnxuE58@2t0DrlRIcCX0hb@EoDrNqDC4Tk6XUA9/NEtNtruv39ANfvAzhTg0@LHtbi5ny9YSijhre@4jFwSIkrX1AopeUjJgtK4yd6zVWScdlIuM8YWpCBPHevX5/Q2BtzVwrUo/BBDY2kplPcm0oyNA5uOn6fgdE6av970coqed/Z4CZ/CR53OwbPKLxd8Sk79Pw)

At first I thought, easy, 30 chars max (which is quite short when manipulating strings in Java). Then the exceptions happened.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 42

Recursive, parameters in reverse order, first y then x. And [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

```
y=>r=x=>x<0?'-'+r(-x):`${x}`.padStart(y,0)
```

**Test**

```js
var F=
y=>r=x=>x<0?'-'+r(-x):`${x}`.padStart(y,0)

;`IN: (1,1)   OUT: "1"
IN: (1,2)   OUT: "01"
IN: (10,1)  OUT: "10"
IN: (-7,3)  OUT: "-007"
IN: (-1,1)  OUT: "-1"
IN: (10,-1) OUT: "10"
IN: (0,0)   OUT: "0"
IN: (0,1)   OUT: "0"
IN: (0,4)   OUT: "0000"`
.split(`\n`).map(r => r.match(/[-\d]+/g))
.forEach(([x,y,k])=>{
  o = F(y)(x)
  ok = o == k
  console.log(ok?'OK':'KO',x,y,'->', o)
})
```

Comment: While impressive, I feel this answer skirts the rules slightly by defining the function `f(y)(x)` instead of `f(x,y)`.

Comment: Reading up on the "currying" rules, I wanted to add that my objection was more with the reversed params and not with the currying itself.

Comment: @styletron the order of the parameters is not specified in the challenge. So I can take advantage of this

Comment: Dang, `y=>r=x=>x<0?'-'+r(-x):(x+='')[y-1]?x:r(0+x)` comes so close...

Comment: i have no issues with people reversing the input order.

Answer (score 5):

## bash, <s>27</s>, 25 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Bruce Forte

```
printf %0$[$2+($1<0)]d $1
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUHVQCVaxUhbQ8XQxkAzNkVBxfD///@GBv@NAQ)

Comment: You can [save two bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUHVQCVaxUhbQ8XQxkAzNkVBxfD///@GBv@NAQ) by inlining the padding length. Also another interesting one (28 bytes): [`printf %\ 0$[1+$1]d $2|xargs`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUE1RsFAJdpQW8UwNkVBxaimIrEovfj///8m/3UNjQA).

Comment: maybe you mean `printf %\ 0$[1+$2]d $1|xargs`, i didn't remember this format for signed numbers also xargs trick to remove leading space

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>56</s> 48 bytes

```
function(x,y)sprintf(paste0("%0",y+(x<0),"d"),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzRCsIwDEXf/YoQEBJMIVVhL@vHyLSwlzq2Ct3X163bKpi3czg3Y/bgsv@ELvbvQElmnoaxD9HT8JjiSwnPijJfKLXKgk9kSZw9WbEMAM4BWjytfD1YN6GlKIGuwjRy24VRbYqytTHHyCzmN1LR@nZj@8f3ysth/gI)

-8 bytes thanks to [djhurio](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13849/djhurio)

#### Explanation

- `sprintf("%0zd",x)` returns `x` as a string padded with zeros to be of length `z`
- `paste0("%0",y+(x<0),"d")` constructs the string `"%0zd"`, where `z` is `y`, plus 1 if `x` is less than zero
- If `z` is less than the number of digits in `x`, `x` is printed as a string as is

Comment: 48 bytes `function(x,y)sprintf(paste0("%0",y+(x<0),"d"),x)`

Comment: @djhurio brilliant! I think that would warrant another answer rather than an edit of mine, what do you say?

Comment: You can make it as an edit. This solution is not so much different, just using different function.

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
Ö±Ωo≥⁰#±:'0s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9odXNr///DlsKxzqlv4oml4oGwI8KxOicwc////zX/LTM0MA)

### Explanation

```
Ö±Ωo≥⁰#±:'0s  Inputs are y=4 and x=-20
           s  Convert x to string: "-20"
        :'0   Prepend '0'
  Ω           until
      #±      the number of digits
   o≥⁰        is at least y: "00-20"
Ö±            Sort by is-digit: "-0020"
              Print implicitly.
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 39 bytes

```
\d+$
$*0
((\d)*),(?<-2>-0+|0)*(0*)
$3$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcchDoAwDABA33eUpC1t0m4CQ0DyiQlIhsAgCJK/D3B3134f59Y6WtZWao@A4kBUKgsrzaOlybx/nIVcGDBjtBYaEJog/IMNmsHV/1m8)

Input should be comma-separated with the number first and the width second.

Answer (score 4):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 23 bytes

```
/oRe./'+Ao
\I*tI&0-R$@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/PyhVT19d2zGfK8ZTq8RTzUA3SMVB//9/Q3MuYwA)

Input should be linefeed-separated with the number on the first line and the width on the second.

#### Explanation

```
/...
\...@/
```

This is the usual framework for linear programs in Ordinal mode. The only catch in this case is this bit:

```
.../...
...&...
```

This causes the IP to enter Cardinal mode vertically and execute just the `&` in Cardinal mode before resuming in Ordinal mode.

Unfolding the zigzag control flow then gives:

```
IRt.&'-A$o*eI/&/0+Ro@

I    Read the first line of input (the value) as a string.
R    Reverse the string.
t.   Split off the last character and duplicate it.
&    Fold the next command over this string. This doesn't really do anything,
     because the string contains only one character (so folding the next
     command is identical to executing it normally).
'-   Push "-".
A    Set intersection. Gives "-" for negative inputs and "" otherwise.
$o   If it's "-", print it, otherwise it must have been a digit which we
     leave on the stack.
*    Join the digit back onto the number. If the number was negative, this
     joins the (absolute value of the) number to an implicit empty string,
     doing nothing.
e    Push an empty string.
I    Read the width W.
/&/  Iterate the next command W times.
0    Append a zero. So we get a string of W zeros on top of the absolute
     value of the input number.
+    Superimpose. This takes the character-wise maximum of both strings
     and appends extraneous characters from the longer string. Since the
     string of zeros can never be larger than the digits in the input,
     the input itself will be uneffected, but extraneous zeros are appended,
     padding the string to the required length.
R    Reverse the result.
o    Print it.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Here are two alternatives, also at 23 bytes, which use Cardinal `H` (*abs*) to get rid of the `-`:

```
/R.I&0-RoH
\Ie#\'+Ao\@/
```

```
/R.H#/.+Xo
\Ie\I&0QRo@/
```

In principle, these are a command shorter, but the `&` doesn't fit into a position where there's a 1-character string on the stack, so we need to skip it with a `#`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>16</strike> 13 bytes

```
‹Ｎ⁰﹪⁺⁺%0ηd↔Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9Rw873e9Y9atzwfueqR427gEjV4Nz2lEdtU97vWXlux///uuZcxgA)

This is the shortest I could get using Charcoal without printing leading or trailing whitespaces. At least I am now starting to understand how to use the `Modulo` function to format strings.

The deverbosed code is as follows:

```
Print(Less(InputNumber(),0));    # Prints a - if the first input is less than 0
Print(Modulo(Add(Add("%0",h),"d"),Abs(Cast(q))));   # q: first input;  h: second input
```

- 3 bytes saved thanks to Neil!

Comment: To print `-` or nothing is really easy in Charcoal: Printing 1 prints `-` while printing 0 prints nothing. So, the ternary is superfluous, saving 3 bytes.

Comment: If you swap the `InputNumber()` with the `Cast(q)`, I think you can then switch to a string comparison to save another byte.

Comment: @Neil I knew that I could simplify the `Ternary`!

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 45 bytes

```php
printf("%0".($argv[2]+(0>$n=$argv[1])).d,$n);
```

or

```php
[,$n,$e]=$argv;printf("%0".($e+(0>$n)).d,$n);       # requires PHP 7.1 or later
```

Run with `-nr` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9074bd4d6a0d2f1f5d395c61858c0278663dc242).

Comment: Getting an error when executing the code in that link.

Comment: @Shaggy The second version requires PHP 7.1

Comment: I went on and on about this, and I arrived to exactly this answer. I believe this is the optimal version

Answer (score 4):

## C, 33 bytes

```
f(x,y){printf("%0*d",y+(x<0),x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0KnUrO6oCgzryRNQ0nVQCtFSadSW6PCxkBTp0LTuvY/UEIhNzEzT0OTq5pLAQjSNAx1FAw1rQtKS4o1lJQ0rRGiRlhEDbAq1jXXUTDGIozDaKAhuljEsZuNU9QEyKn9DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 118 bytes

```
(j=ToString;If[#2<=0,j@#,If[(z=IntegerLength@#)>=#2,t=z,t=#2];s=j/@PadLeft[IntegerDigits@#,t];If[#>=0,""<>s,"-"<>s]])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xCoMwFEX3foaBopDQmA4d9EmGLoKD0G6SIbRJjKAFfZM/n6aloB0uj8O7nDtq7M2o0T90sBDSAe6vG85@ckVtOyJK4HSQhEZIV6gnNM7MjZkc9pJkFRBBEdYYIlSxwHCSrX42xmL3616987hEA6qvsYrCJCmrhSbsc5TKjqGNgyhtl9NcHTYQO@D7F7vQ80ac8r8iy1V4Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```
If[#<0,"-",""]<>IntegerString[#,10,Max[#2,IntegerLength@#,1]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYuxCsMgFEX3fMVDIdMLaJrSoWlxDTRQ6CgOUtRkiJTgUAh@u3WoJNu595676DCZRYf5rZO9pcFK2jMkDUFCVH8ffDDOrK@wzt5JipzhqL@StvhfHsa7MIm8KFWnUX/kM6tBWiGoqhG2CgA2jsAjFmwLsr1uLginwkc9O00JmdmOh7Yrz3O2u1hFdU0/)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think this isn't quite doing what you want. You probably meant `IntegerLength` instead of `IntegerDigits`. You can save a byte by using `IntegerLength@#` instead of `IntegerLength[#]` though.

Comment: Thank you! I was copying the code from another computer by hand where I was testing it and I indeed mistyped IntegerDigits for IntegerLength. It should work now. I have also added a TIO link with all the test cases in the challenge description (+1) showing that it works as expected. Thank you also for the suggestion for saving an extra byte! I don't know how I missed it before. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 54 bytes

```hs
x#y|s<-show$abs$x=['-'|x<0]++('0'<$[length s+1..y])++s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0K5sqbYRrc4I79cJTGpWKXCNlpdV72mwsYgVltbQ91A3UYlOic1L70kQ6FY21BPrzJWU1u7@H9uYmaegq1CSj6XAhAUlJYElxT55CmoKBgqKCsYYhM0whA0wKZUQ9dcEyhujC4OUmyA1QgNXUPN/wA)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 29 bytes

Using Excel's `TEXT` functionality ("Converts a value to text in a specific number format").

`x` in A1, `y` in B1

```
=TEXT(A1,REPT("0",MAX(1,B1)))
```

Comment: You can drop the `)))` for -3 Bytes by converting to Google Sheets

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 44 bytes

```matlab
@(x,y)fprintf(['%0',num2str(y+(x<0)),'d'],x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KnUjOtoCgzryRNI1pd1UBdJ68016i4pEijUlujwsZAU1NHPUU9VqdC83@ahqGOkSYXVLF6TJ66Jleahq65jjGGoKGBjqHmfwA)

Comment: [For 31 bytes](https://tio.run/##TcxBCoMwEIXhfU@RjZjUSXhTBTcVvEpRA27aoiLx9GmMs@jsPv7HfIbttU/Rd8652OtAh1m/y/zevC4L3MeSjkqHJwwFE71mYqOUKhTfTjwuIAu5pYQk21KdZYH2NEu1srWJsgVB/mTwPxpBuvgD "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: If leading + signs are allowed for positive numbers (waiting to hear from op if ok), this works [for 28](https://tio.run/##TcxBDkAwEIXhvVN0I1qmzQwSK4mrCJrYIIjo6atqFmb35X@ZdTj7a/K2Ncb4Tt7g1LHt83JamaUF5mMGriC4lbeSgJQQIhWUvCg/YBTGFhIG6QaqKI3YvCaumrc6kLcIyH8i6I@aEc4/ "Octave – Try It Online").

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

```
s r"%d+"_ù0V
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=cyByIiVkKyJf+TBW&input=LTcsMw==)

Comment: It's a bit cheaper to keep the minus sign in and just mess with the digits: [Test it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=cyByIiVkKyJf+TBW&input=LTcsMw==)

Comment: @ETHproductions: Or take `x` as a string for [10 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ci9cZCsvX/lUVg==&input=Ii03Iiwz).

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks fellas. I'll update it when I get back to my desk.

Comment: @Shaggy Looks like you posted your own answer, so I'll use ETHproduction's trick. Thanks though.

Comment: Oliver, that 10-byter is just @ETHproduction's 12-byte solution upgraded to Japt 2.0a0 with `U` as a string allowing us to golf off the first 2 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>31</s> 28 bytes

Thanks [Carl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149620/the-leading-zeroes-challenge/149657?noredirect=1#comment365719_149657) for saving 3 bytes using interpolation.

```ruby
->x,y{"%0#{y+(x<0?1:0)}d"%x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165Cp7JaSdVAubpSW6PCxsDe0MpAszZFSbWi9n9BaUmxQlq0oY5BLBeUbaBjCmcb6hgiJHQNDXSMY/8DAA)

Comment: 28: ->x,y{"%0#{y+(x<0?1:0)}d"%x}

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>25</s> 40 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)$a|% *g $("D$b"*($b|% *o 0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJUyWxRlVBK11BRUPJRSVJSUtDJQkkkK9goKn5//9/DV1jc00gaaoJAA)

### Explanation

This calls `.ToString()` on the number with a generated format string, but multiplies it by -1, 0, or 1 based on whether `$b` (`y`) is negative, 0, or positive respectively; this is to handle negative `y` values which format strings don't by themselves.

This seems to require wrapping negative numbers in a substatement `()` for it to work which is just a quirk of the invocation when using literals; if passed variables of type integer, it would not need that.

Comment: It looks like both of these fail when `y` is negative.

Comment: @Shaggy ugh good catch. Removed second solution altogether and fixed up the first, thanks!

Comment: Ouch, 15 bytes! Sorry!

Comment: @Shaggy heh, one of these days I'll actually write the PowerShell-based golfing language I've been thinking about. This actually pushed me to research a bit more and get closer to starting it, so thanks for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

## C# 6.0, 35 bytes

```
(x,y)=>(x.ToString($"D{y<0?0:y}"));
```

#### Alternative solution (51 bytes)

```
(x,y)=>(x.ToString(string.Format("D{0}",y<0?0:y)));
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>90</s> <s>86</s> 83 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@x y=if(y<0)"-"""+++{if(c>'-')c'0'\\c<-rjustify x[k\\k<-:toString y]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcy7CsIwFADQ3a@4ZImlBAoOgqTSQQfBLaNxCGlT0uYhSSoN4q8bO57lSDMIV6zvFzOAFdoVbV8@JGCpv7r3rlsht1rtM20qRBBCdV1/NsszJriSuMGcS0rCtMSkVYb1MXM@U3JKnqWg3Qj5@S0sia1soYMDkGP5SWXEGAu53cslO2G1jH8)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 22 + 1 (-`n`) = 23 bytes

```
printf"%0*d",<>+/-/,$_
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1J1UArhUtJx8ZOW19XX0cl/v9/Qy4QNOIyNABSuuZcxly6YCEDEG0AhiDa5F9@QUlmfl7xf908AA)

Comment: Loops infinitely on `10,-1`

Comment: fixed `+5 bytes`

Comment: found another solution `-5 bytes`

Comment: Sweet. I'm working on one as well... stay tuned

Comment: I managed it in [26 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149654/2771)

Comment: your comment just appeared, while I found also a similar solution, indeed the newline is not necessary -> 23 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 30 bytes

```
[@x'@:'!'\d+'['0'x pad]1/repl]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P9qhQt3BSl1RPSZFWz1a3UC9QqEgMSXWUL8otSAn9r@DVRpXdJpCSmZxQayCg1VOVTKXgqECEMFYRmCWoQFMLN5cQcEYwoKrA8rGQ3UA1RnAWQgxExDrPwA)

Highlighted:

[image: just the above thing]

### Explanation

```
[@x'@:'!'\d+'['0'x pad]1/repl]
[                            ]   anonymous function, take two args: (y x)
 @x                              name pad length argument
   '@:'!                         convert to string*
        '\d+'[        ]1/repl    replace all runs of digits with...
              '0'x pad              ...the digits padded to x '0's
```

### Stringification

Usually, one would use `tostr` to convert something to a string; however, due to the way string formatting works...

```
'@:'!
    !   format the string
'@:'    apply the `:` function t the top of the stack
        this creates a sub-stack, and : duplicates.
        the formatting obtains the top value, which is just the original TOS,
        and casts it to a string
```

The reason we use `'@:'!` instead of `tostr` is to avoid the space between `@x` and `tostr`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 45 bytes

```c
f(x,y){printf("%s%0*i","-"+(x>=0),y,abs(x));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BCsIwDIDhu09RAoNEU0hV8FD0XWah0oNj2A06xp69luFhuOb48YfE6ZdzOXtMPNHcf0I3eIQmNnIMwKDhhOlxF@KJ22fERGSXXCL1bkOHpOaDR8OGrCrTj0NEALIrnisov3SL@saXPZpKWdb1qlsUlv0hqb0kfP3HJX8B)

### Explanation

`printf` formats three arguments:

```c
%s      ->    "-"+(x>=0)
%0*i    ->    y
        ->    abs(x)
```

`%s` formats the string `"-"+(x>=0)`. `"-"` is really just an address, something like `41961441`. In memory, this looks something like this:

```c
MEMORY ADDRESS | 41961441  41961442 ...
VALUE          | 45 ('-')  0 (0x00) ...
```

When formatted into a string, C takes the address (say 41961441) and keeps on acquiring characters until a null byte (0x00) is met. When x is less than zero, the value `"-"+(x>=0)` has that of the original address (41961441). Otherwise, `x>=0` is 1, so the expression becomes `"-"+1`, which points the null byte after `"-"`, which prints nothing.

`%0*i` prints an integer padded with a specified number of `0`s. `y` denotes this number. We pad `abs(x)` to avoid the negative in some arguments.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 25 + `-n` flag = 26 bytes

```
printf"%0*d",<>+($_<0),$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1J1UArRUnHxk5bQyXexkBTRyX@/39dcy7jf/kFJZn5ecX/dfMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>39 31</s>  30 bytes

```perl6
->\a,\b{'-'x(0>a)~a.abs.fmt("\%0{b}d")}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##bZDBTsJAEIbv@xSTDdhd2C1bNZBQWrl60QuerIcCS9KEloZWg8HyMHr0Gbj4QjxCnW5KaYx7mEy@@f/ZmUn1dj0sXzMNb0N74ZL4Ha4Wm6UGr5R@EIpgvrektWPKD/khtMN5Zq/inNGgq/bzYkl5UaJlmussBw/WUaIzOw7TMewJQDzAAHA6frLT8QsOVcar7Hk6iRLfY3bvjr/0oAuWsIwUwdlCG4vJOhO9S/Ui10vj4ygbuBgY9H@@TTsBh5YIOClItdcMR3NJug4T6Js5XbLabOuRpY8NplEioHN2AjezRxlUd2AfWOWtsgCKxE7xboyD518qNaOkKO8fxsAc4XBc5fFpNgbqUFLD6wtUDVVGW0tVTeVI3DRUKjU6c6ellq0eEvGfHkqo1n8NdP6Dty2Ij/4C)

```perl6
->\a,\b{a.fmt("\%0{b+(0>a)}d")}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##bZDBboJAEIbv@xSTjdZdXXBpG01EKNde2os9lR4Q14REkAht2lB8mPbYZ/DiC/kIdNggkqZ72Ey@@f9/ZzZVu82kes0UvE3M0CbxB1yF25UCpzJcPxD@sgjMdZwz6vdlsRwx6Qa8XFFeVij1cpXl4MAmSlRmxkE6g4IAxGO8AE6HL3Y6fMO@rnhdPXvzKHEdZg7v@MsQ@jAQAy1FcLbQ1qKr3ly9pyrM1Ur7OMrGNl4MRscfHSdg3xEBJyWp91ngaDZJN0ECIz2nTdbbXTOy4WKAFyUCemcncD17lEG9P/vELu@0BVAkZor/xTg47qXTMErK6v5hBswSFsdVHp8WM6AWJQ28vkDZUqm1jVQ21JiKm5YaUk7P3OqojU6GgfhPhhSy814Lrf/gbQfiob8)

```perl6
{$^a.fmt: '%0'~$^b+(0>$a)~'d'}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##bZDBToNAEIbv@xQTQmW3LHRR0yZQsFcveqknYxNstwkJUFLQaGp5GD36DL34Qn0EHDaUbox72Ey@@f9/Z7aQ23TcvJQSXsfuMiDZO1wsNysJYbMzF7G7ziofrIGwanPxbFMRmTGrrZW1b1A5q2RZQQhpksvSzeLChx0ByEZ4ARwPn/R4@IK6rVhbPc6mSR6F1B3esKchDMDilpIiOFmM3qIqcyrfCrms5Er5GMpGAV4U7J9vFceh1kTAyJ6068xxtIAUaZyDreYMyHqz7UZ2IgyYJTkH8@QEpmZPSmjXpx/YZVqbg4HELfC7KIMwOnc6ZpB9c3vnA/W4x3CV@4e5D4ZnkA5enqHoqVDaTio66kz4VU8dISYn7mlqR8twEP/JEFxo7/XQ@w9eaxCP8Qs)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with placeholder parameters ｢$a｣ and ｢$b｣

  $^a         # declare and use first parameter
  .fmt:       # format it 

  '%0'        # '%05d'
  ~
    $^b       # make it ｢$b｣ digits wide
    + (0>$a)  # add 1 if ｢$a｣ is negative
  ~
 'd'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## **PHP, 49 bytes**

```
echo str_pad($argv[1],$argv[2],'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Instead of `STR_PAD_LEFT`, you can use `0`. Also, this fails for `-7,3` (returns `0-7` instead of `-007`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 18 bytes

Likely not the right approach, this [is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149739/48198) <s>feels</s> really long for [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), but there wasn't one already.

```
F+Ṁ+R'0-Ld⁰¹↕='-s⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/30374c4G7SB1A12flEeNGw7tfNQ21VZdtxjI/v//v/F/XXMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
aR+XD0Xb-#_._
```

Takes the number and minimum number of digits as command-line arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MUg7wsUgIklXOV4v/v///7rm/40B)

#### Explanation

```
               a, b are cmdline args; XD is regex `\d` (implicit)
aR             In the number a, replace
  +XD           a run of digits (regex `\d+`)
                with this callback function:
     0X          0 string-multiplied by
       b-#_      minimum digit count minus length of match
           ._    to which concatenate the match itself
               Autoprint the result of the replacement
```

Since string-multiplication gives an empty string when the right operand is negative, this works correctly for all test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
0;$L<⁹$$¿
ṣ”-Ç€0¦j”-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/AWsXH5lHjThWVQ/u5Hu5c/Khhru7h9kdNawwOLcsCcf7//6@ka6703xgA)

Take first input `x` as a string.

Apparently there is no existing Jelly answer...

`L<¥` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>95</s> 89 bytes

```
	DEFINE('F(X,B)')
F	L =GT(B) B
	N =LT(X) 1
	F =DUPL('-',N) LPAD(-1 ^ N * X,L,0)	:(RETURN)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcyxCgMhDADQOX5FNpPiwQk3FRwqailIKkcEpw6dS2/o/2Pp3PUN7/M@nsdrm5ByuUkmW2i4yJbhTMr/bApUDFelyBgNCIaqNBi9gYIh9VbJLtYJY22XRIvHBwqecLjq1l@6Z@278FS4d21dMRTyq9vYZEnzCw)

defining a function is equivalent to a full program in bytes, so I figured I'd do this instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `j`, 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
AṘṛ$ʂṄ'-×
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUElRTElQjklOTglRTElQjklOUIlMjQlQ0ElODIlRTElQjklODQnLSVDMyU5NyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PS03JTBBMyZmbGFncz1q)

##### Explanation

```python
AṘṛ$ʂṄ'-×  '# Implicit input
AṘ          # Take the absolute value and convert to string
  ṛ         # Pad with zeros to length of second input
   $ʂṄ      # Check if the first input was negative
      '-×  '# If it was, push a "-"
            # Implicit output of joined stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 70 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.75 bytes

```
ȧS∆Z¹±SṪp
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiyKdT4oiGWsK5wrFT4bmqcCIsIiIsIi03XG4zIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
1001110000000100000100010000100111100010101011011000110001011000011111
```

Idk why Vyxal 2 doesnt have an "is negative?" element but i found a way around that

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 46 bytes

```
proc Z n\ p {format %0[expr $n<0?$p+1:$p]d $n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFKIS9GoUChOi2/KDexREHVIDq1oqBIQSXPxsBepUDb0EqlIDYFyK39X1BaUqwQHaVgqGAYq6DAheAaoXANQNJwrq65gjEy1xBFFqhY1zAWzjVQMEA2ygDVIgMFk9j/AA)

Answer (score 0):

### Swift, 37 bytes (65 inside a function):

```
String(format:"%0\(y+(x<0 ?1:0))d",x)
```

Inside a function:

```
func c(x:Int,y:Int){print(String(format:"%0\(y+(x<0 ?1:0))d",x))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 218 bytes

```
 import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;interface B{static void main(String z[]){int x=Integer.parseInt(z[1]);if(x>z[0].length()){System.out.printf(StringUtils.leftPad(z[0],x,"0"));}else{System.out.printf(z[0]);}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

interface B {
   static void main(String z[]) {
      int x = Integer.parseInt(z[1]);
      if (x > z[0].length()) {
        System.out.printf(StringUtils.leftPad(z[0], x, "0"));
      } else {
        System.out.printf(z[0]);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC, ~163 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 DIM A(SGN PI,VAL "2")
 2 LET A(SGN PI,SGN PI)=NOT PI
 3 LET A(SGN PI,VAL "2")=INT PI
 4 IF A(SGN PI,SGN PI)<NOT PI THEN PRINT "-";
 5 IF A(SGN PI,VAL "2")=SGN PI THEN GOTO INT PI*PI
 6 FOR I=VAL "2" TO A(SGN PI,VAL "2")
 7 PRINT NOT PI;
 8 NEXT I
 9 PRINT ABS A(SGN PI,SGN PI)
```

Explanations: ZX81 BASIC is quite costly when storing numbers as each number is stored as a 5 byte (I think) floating point number even if you store an integer value like 1. Even line numbers cost 5 bytes per line, then add in the `NEW LINE` character at the end of each line, and the lowest byte count for a BASIC line in Sinclair ZX81 BASIC is 7 (for instance, `1 PRINT`). `SGN PI` is 1, and costs fewer bytes than `1` on this basis, NOT PI is `0` and costs two bytes etc.

- Line `1` sets up a numeric array `1, 2`; arrays are not zero-indexed in this case.
- Line `2` sets `A[1, 1]` to zero.
- Line `3` sets `A[1, 2]` to 3, so the test case is `(1,3)`.
- Line `4` tests to see if the number to be printed is negative; if so, a minus sign is displayed.
- Line `5` checks if the padding is set to 1, if so we don't need to print any leading zeros.
- Line `6` then loops through from 2 to the value of our padding (in this case, 3).
- Line `7` prints the leading zeros.
- Line `8` ends the loop.
- Line `9` prints the positive value of our `A[1,1]`, which in this case is zero.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
R¬+Ṛ}AṚṾ€”-x⁴<0¤¤;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o0Brthztn1ToCiYc79z1qWvOoYa5uxaPGLTYGh5YcWmL9//9/0/@6hkbGAA)

Takes `y` and `x` (in that order) as integers.

**Explanation**

Example input `5` and `-123`.

```
R¬+Ṛ}AṚṾ€”-x⁴<0¤¤;  Dyadic link
R¬                  Not the range of y. This gives a list of y zeroes. [0,0,0,0,0]
   Ṛ}               Reverse the digits of x. [-3,-2,-1]
  +                 Add these lists. [-3,-2,-1,0,0]
     A              Absolute value. [3,2,1,0,0].
      Ṛ             Reverse. [0,0,1,2,3]
       Ṿ€           Make each digit a string. '00123'
         ”-         The character '-'.
            ⁴<0     x<0? 0 or 1. (1 in this example)
           x        Repeat '-' 0 or 1 times
               ¤¤   Closes ”-x⁴<0 as a nilad
                 ;  Prepend '-' to '00123'
```

The absolute difference atom `ạ` would work here over `+` making `A` unnecessary except for the case where `y` is zero or negative where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 33 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input as `n` from `[A1]` and `length` from `[B1]` and outputs the appropriately formatted string to the VBE immediate window

```vb
?Format([A1],[Rept(0,Max(1,B1))])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 40 characters

```
<y><D>,<N>=$1@subst{\\ =0;@right{$3;$2}}
```

(Not really for Gema. For some weird reason it can only pad with spaces.)

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ gema '<y><D>,<N>=$1@subst{\\ =0;@right{$3;$2}}' <<< '-7,3'
-007
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/36bSzsbFTsfGz85WxdChuDSpuKQ6JkbB1sDaoSgzPaOkWsXYWsWotvb/f11zHWMA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lVCxboMwEJ3jr7habpxIWDFJpQyJEZXaoUsrZQVUEXACagoIO1Irmm@nNqCUoR3q4e493zvfO@9jlbWpTE5xLYHdg5ZKvyaxkmKGJgF1HZdGgrq0J0tL@MD4UOMdZWtnZSnjfN1fDL3sKmdjPXd499hA3DG564g5FM0Rquq80AegX3DLXK7gl7w0MSwo0KeiOmuTd1KdTxY8flQy0TI18OWNInQoa8ityETApLm5Lhz40QVvIC3RpO66BSYzkElWArPSrgubaYuy0oujfI8Xqk46ALTdfnrbB8/ZPnuCuL4675VuwhAE3/h1fsx0Q1YbsrxcWgpzjNDkH0tdR2PSG7Oo@fHdl415sIaDYKQT4i9pFMF02m9nP8aaSstCtt8)